# Typescript generic function doesn't complain about callback return type

Tags: typescript

Typescript generic function doesn't complain about callback return type. Shouldn't it complain that types do not match like it does with the object? Why this is a valid typescript?

```
const a = <T>(shape: T | (() => T)): T => {
    return shape instanceof Function ? shape() : shape;
}

const func = () => ({ x: '', o: '' });
a<{ x: string }>(func); // this should fail to compile

a<{ x: string }>({ x: '', o: '' }); // fails to compile
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/MYewdgzgLgBAhjAvDAPAFQHwAoIAs4AOApgFwxowA+MWWAlEhuXXWRYkwN4BQMfMAJyJQArgLAw8hIjACWkKHDDAiIAGYwAYiOVRZ4GAH5J+YvRhkpxANzcAvr35PuoBTDU7gSGgw41OMAAeZADkIQA0MCChITB2dLZwKAHBklAC8gDmcdgeygkwAPSFMFC4shAmICIANgAm7nCyNaUgMKAAtgTNRNzcSSmW6Vk5WIMwYZHRE7Hx1kUlak01lVBtnd01REA)

Comment: Your playground link underlines some of the code with the message `Argument of type '{ x: string; o: string; }' is not assignable to parameter of type '{ x: string; } | (() => { x: string; })'.
  Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'o' does not exist in type '{ x: string; } | (() => { x: string; })'` - isnt that exactly what you expected?

Comment: @Jamiec The confusion is why it doesn't underline **2** parts of the code. There's an inconsistency. Interestingly, passing `const func = () => ({ g: '',f:'' });` fails, implying that there's at least some type-checking in action.

Comment: @spender correct, I expect for it to fail in both calls. Looks like it completely fails only if function return type completely mismatches generic type.

Comment: Your func defined in this way, implicitly returns any type. Type your const as fn with the right return type, and it will complain

Comment: @quirimmo hover `func` in playground link. It evaluates function type to `const func: () => { x: string; o: string; }` not to `any` type

Comment: This is because excess property checking is only done for object literals. If you define `const obj = {x: '', o: ''};` and then call `a<{x: string}>(obj);` it is not an error, because `obj` is a variable, not a literal. On the other hand, if you pass the *function literal* directly instead of defining a constant named `func`, then it doesn't complain because a *function literal* is not an *object literal*.

Comment: @quirimmo It implicitly returns `{x:string;o:string}`, not `any`. Being more explicit elsewhere `const func: () => { x: string;o:string } = () => ({ x: '', o:'' })` still allows `func` to be used where we might not expect it to be valid.

Comment: @kaya3 Is there a way to force the complains? For example that generic would only allow functions with explicit return type?

Comment: There might be, but at that point you are fighting against the [Liskov substitution principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle), which says `func` is a fine argument for type `() => T` because it satisfies every property that a `() => T` is expected to satisfy; that's because it returns an object which satisfies every property that an object of type `T` is expected to satisfy. The type `{x: string}` **doesn't** require the object not to have more properties. Passing an object literal with excess properties is a probable mistake, but not actually unsafe, type-wise...

Comment: ...whereas passing a non-literal object that happens to have excess properties, or a function which *returns* an object that happens to have excess properties, is usually not a mistake.

Comment: @spender look the other answers above, in this way it does not. Add `as const` if using 3.4 or higher that will be typed  correctly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a known TypeScript bug. [Github issue](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12632) which requires a [fix](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/241).

Haven't found a proper workaround

Answer (score 0):

contextual type (in your case `a<{ x: string }>(func);` ) do not perform excess property check, there's no spec about this, so maybe that's by design